# Could not parse Master URL: 'spark:http://localhost:18080'

Tags: java, twitter, spark-streaming

When I'm trying to run my code it throws this `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL:spark:http://localhost:18080
```

This is my code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name").setMaster("spark:http://localhost:18080").set("spark.ui.port","18080");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));
String[] filet=new String[]{"Obama","ISI"};

JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> reciverStream=TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,filet);
JavaDStream<String> statuses = reciverStream.map(new Function<Status, String>() {
     public String call(Status status) { return status.getText(); }
     }
      );
ssc.start();
ssc.awaitTermination();}}
```

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you specify 2 schemas in the URL you pass to `SparkConf.setMaster()`.

The `spark` is the schema, so you don't need to add `http` after `spark`. See the javadoc of [`SparkConf.setMaster()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html#setMaster(java.lang.String)) for more examples.

So the master URL you should be using is `"spark://localhost:18080"`. Change this line:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")
    .setMaster("spark://localhost:18080").set("spark.ui.port","18080");
```

Comment: thanks for responding, when i change it and run it again he throws another Exception:                                                                               

Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost:18080: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost:18080]

Comment: @Anas It is most likely because you haven't started a server or it is on a different port than the one you specified (`18080`).

Comment: thanks for helping, when i change little bit in the code i used port 8080 

**String host="LocalHost";
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")      .setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.driver.host",host).set("spark.driver.port","8080");**

he give me this INFO:
**(INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Connection established)**

but i still can't see the tweets!!

Comment: this works for me: SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")
    .setMaster("spark://192.168.30.154:7077").set("spark.ui.port","7077");

Answer (score 5):

The standard port for master is 7077 not 18080.  Maybe you can try 7077.