# Error initializing SparkContext on Mac

Tags: java, apache-spark

I tried to run my scala application using eclipse on mac OS Sierra and I am getting this error when i run it.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/09/20 11:32:29 INFO StreamingExamples: Setting log level to [WARN] for 
streaming example. To override add a custom log4j.properties to the classpath.
17/09/20 11:32:30 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library 
for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/09/20 11:32:31 WARN Utils: Your hostname, 127.0.0.1 resolves to a loopback 
address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.254.169.69 instead (on interface en0)
17/09/20 11:32:31 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/09/20 11:32:33 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'Local[*]'
at 


org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskSchedule (SparkContext.scala:2735)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522) at 
    org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
        at bigdata.spark_applications.mapr$.main(mapr.scala:30)
        at bigdata.spark_applications.mapr.main(mapr.scala)
    17/09/20 11:32:33 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'Local[*]' at
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2735)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
        at bigdata.spark_applications.mapr$.main(mapr.scala:30)
        at bigdata.spark_applications.mapr.main(mapr.scala)
```

Please can anybody help me. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

According to the error log, you have the wrong master url. Please, check following [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250527/could-not-parse-master-url-sparkhttp-localhost18080).